# Preg_replace delete all iframes, except the last one

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Im triying to delete all iframes but keeping the last iframe.

here is my loaded html

```
<br />CAP 01:<br /><iframe src="mysitevideo.com/embed-291dz33facsl-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />CAP 02: <br /><iframe src="http://mysitevideo.com/embed-3bp1mdixoiyc-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />CAP 03: <br /><iframe src="http://mysitevideo.com/embed-0d213t7vp8f2-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />
```

Outputs should be: `<iframe src="http://mysitevideo.com/embed-0d213t7vp8f2-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

this is my function

```
function DELiframeEXCEPTlast($str){
$str = preg_replace('#<iframe src="(.*?)" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>#','',$str);
return $str;
}
```

My code deletes all ocurrences. any ideas to keep the last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
function DELiframeEXCEPTlast($str){
  $pattern='#<iframe src="(.*?)" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>#';
  return preg_replace($pattern,'',$str,preg_match_all($pattern,$str)-1);
}
```

Comment: `preg_match_all()` doesn't return a string nor an array. It returns a boolean value.

Comment: It returns the count of matches, and the preg_replace() limit argument can use this to replace all except the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_split` and return the last item in the returned array.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Though using regex for this isn't the best idea.  You really should look at using the DOM object in php for doing this.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 1):

You can just set another iframe in regexp like follows:

```
function DELiframeEXCEPTlast($str){
$str = preg_replace('#(<iframe[^>]*></iframe>)*.*(<iframe[^>]*></iframe>)#','$2',$str);
return $str;
}
var_dump(DELiframeEXCEPTlast('<br />CAP 01:<br /><iframe src="mysitevideo.com/embed-291dz33facsl-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />CAP 02: <br /><iframe src="http://mysitevideo.com/embed-3bp1mdixoiyc-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />CAP 03: <br /><iframe src="http://mysitevideo.com/embed-0d213t7vp8f2-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />'));
```

that will outputs

```
string(104) "<iframe src="http://mysitevideo.com/embed-0d213t7vp8f2-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your regex is replacing all of the iframes is because it is matching all the iframes. Try using `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` to find out what would be found (which, in turn, is the list of what would be replaced)

If you really want to do this via regular expressions (which is generally considered "**a bad thing**") then add an `id` tag to each `<iframe...></iframe>` structure and then add that to the regular expression and see where that will get you.

There are plenty of answers on here which recommend using the DOM functions in PHP to alter HTML code rather than regular expression. I've not used them personally (never had to adjust HTML via PHP before) but that would probably be a better route to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're parsing and modifying HTML I would highly recommend `DOM Parser`. Consider this code:

```
$html = '<br />CAP 01:<br /><iframe src="mysitevideo.com/embed-291dz33facsl-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />CAP 02: <br /><iframe src="http://mysitevideo.com/embed-3bp1mdixoiyc-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />CAP 03: <br /><iframe src="http://mysitevideo.com/embed-0d213t7vp8f2-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nlist = $xpath->query("//iframe");

$numnodes = $nlist->length;
// run loop till $numnodes-1
for($i=0; $i < $numnodes-1; $i++) {
   $node = $nlist->item($i);
   // delete it
   $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$newHTML =  $doc->saveHTML();
echo $newHTML;
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><br>CAP 01:<br><br>CAP 02: <br><br>CAP 03: <br>
<iframe src="http://mysitevideo.com/embed-0d213t7vp8f2-540x320.html" width="540" height="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br></body></html>
```